# basic permutations question

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I've recently asked myself, "given a set B with k many non-repeating members, find an expression in terms of k that gives the number of non-repeating permutations you can form with B and all its subsets." I have speculated that the answer is k+(k-1)k!, because for example with the set {1} you have 1 permutation, with the set containing {1,2} you have 4 permutations, set {1,2,3} you have 15, and I think that expression gives these answers. But I do not know how to prove this expression holds for all cases, in fact I have no idea where or how to even begin with such a proof.
So my question is, if I wanted to perform such a proof myself - or if I just wanted to be able to think about permutations and combinations in general more rigorously - what are some good resources for learning how to do that?

Comment: What is your definition of a "permutation" ? For example with $k=2$, you find $n=4$ "permutations" ? What are they ? Knowing that the "power set" (set of all subsets) of $\{a,b\}$ is $\{\varnothing, \{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$ and has 4 elements.

Comment: It's sequence [A0007526](http://oeis.org/A007526), which is one less than [A000522](http://oeis.org/A000522) since you are not counting the empty list as one of the permutations.

Comment: Thanks to @Jaap Scherphuis I have understood : it is the 4 elements $a, b, ab, ba$ then the 15 elements $a,b,c,ab,ba,bc,cb,ac,ca,abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba$, etc. Giving examples is always important in the exposition of a problem...